# Multi-platform copy files to Azure Blob storage from Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-file-copy

I want to copy the build results from my Azure release pipeline to Azure blob storage.
Currently I use AzureFileCopy@4, which works fine when I build using a Windows agent. But it does not support Linux or MacOS, as I get this error:

> ##[error]The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For
> example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.

How can I make a Blob storage file copy-task that works multi-platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Azure CLI Task to run "az storage blob" command

Comment: So I need to add som pipeline steps to install and run AzCopy?

Comment: Sorry, original answer will not work. Have updated the answer